# how to check for np.nan in list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, nan

I have a function that is supposed to return a tuple of integers or np.nan.

```
return tuple(int(round(n)) if n is not np.nan else n for n in r)
```

The code looks fine to me but I get the following error and I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-368ab2ecd3f3> in <module>()
      6 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") #ignore numpy warnings
      7 for k,v in bb_mapping.items():
----> 8     print(k, map_overview(v))

<ipython-input-2-6f1dc6e291ee> in map_overview(map_tuples)
    120 
    121     r = (np.mean(bb_len), np.std(bb_len), np.mean(ins_len), np.std(ins_len))
--> 122     return tuple(int(round(n)) if n is not np.nan else n for n in r)
    123 
    124 def print_sbar(n,m,s='|#.|',size=30,message=''):

<ipython-input-2-6f1dc6e291ee> in <genexpr>(.0)
    120 
    121     r = (np.mean(bb_len), np.std(bb_len), np.mean(ins_len), np.std(ins_len))
--> 122     return tuple(int(round(n)) if n is not np.nan else n for n in r)
    123 
    124 def print_sbar(n,m,s='|#.|',size=30,message=''):

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

How can I get this error if I am explicitly checking for np.nan values before converting them to integer?

Weird enough, if I manually check the return code, the list comprehension works as expected:

```
>>> print(tuple(int(round(n)) if n is not np.nan else n for n in [12.6,np.nan,0.5,4.6]))
(13, nan, 0, 5)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you comparing with `is`? Different values may not necessarily be the same instance. This is true for ints as well as floats. (CPython's quirk for small integers is the only exception that I know of, and is strictly an implementation detail.)

```
>>> import math
>>> float('nan') is math.nan
False
```

You can use `np.isnan` to check for nan, or the built-in `math.isnan`, or check that the value is equal to itself.

```
>>> np.isnan([12.6,np.nan,0.5,4.6])
array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> [math.isnan(x) for x in [12.6,np.nan,0.5,4.6]]
[False, True, False, False]
>>> [x for x in [12.6,np.nan,0.5,4.6] if x == x]
[12.6, 0.5, 4.6]
```

Comment: I was sure that `np.nan` would be instantiated only once and that `is` was the correct way to check it. Thanks for the tip, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I am using it on a pandas DataFrame, I usually prefer pandas built in isnull to take care of default types. This also avoids other TypeError like `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd

[pd.isnull(i) for i in [1,2,np.nan,4,5]]
```